# Matplotlib not plotting all points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3D-Array in matplotlib, but I only see a linear output. The expected output was a 10x10x10 cube.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

points = np.zeros((10, 10, 10))
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(10):
            points[x][y][z] = z

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at your matrix, just by printing it?  You have 10 rows on 10 planes that are all identical.  So, points[:,0] == points[:,1] == points[:,2].  In each case, you are telling it to plot the points [0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], etc, up to [9,9,9].  That's what it plotted.

Comment: Well wouldn't it be [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2] etc. When I print x, y, z in the 3rd for loop that's what I see

Comment: Did you print `points[:,0]` and `points[:,1]` and `points[:,2]`?  Those are the planes you are passing in as the x points, the y points, and the z points, and those planes are all identical.  It's going to plot the points by picking one from each in corresponding positions.  Since the planes are identical, it will plot [n,n,n] for n between 0 and 9.  If you were trying to plot 1000 different points in a 10x10x10 grid, I'll post an answer that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you were very, very close.  I didn't realize how close until I tried it. The problem you had was that you made points a 3D array where each entry had a value.  It needed to be a 2D array, 1000 x 3.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

points = []
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(10):
            points.append((x,y,z))

points = np.array(points)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(points[:,0],points[:,1],points[:,2])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah yes, I attempted this but was missing converting it to an np array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a good answer by Tim. However, there are alternatives approaches. For example, there is `np.meshgrid()` that are often used in your situation to produce and manipulate data. Here is the code to generate array of data and produce sample plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

n1 = 10  #number of grid rows/columns
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n1),np.arange(n1))

for i in np.arange(n1):
    zg = np.ones(xg.shape) * i
    ax.scatter(xg, yg, zg, s=3, c='k')

lim = n1 + 0.1*n1
ax.set_xlim3d(-0.1*n1, lim)
ax.set_ylim3d(-0.1*n1, lim)
ax.set_zlim3d(-0.1*n1, lim)

# set viewing angle
ax.azim = 120   # z rotation (default=270); 160+112
ax.elev = 35    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 10    # zoom (define perspective)

plt.show()
```

[image: cube2]

Comment: I was reading about meshgrid, great to see it in practice. Thanks!